# Strongloop sneakily added property field to acl object

Tags: strongloop

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Define+access+controls

In the above tutorial, how did the `slc loopback:acl` command added the property to the acl object of review?

```
  {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create" //how did this get added ?
    },
```

When I ran the command myself, no property:create was added. If I try to rename the property as "create_review", and edit the remote hook 
instead of

```
Review.beforeRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
```

to

```
Review.beforeRemote('create_review', function(context, user, next) {
```

I get error 401 unauthorized.

**What are other such property other than create? Why do we require property in acls? Is it to add remote hooks?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access types and their properties are defined in https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access

besides create, there are find, findById, upsert, etc.

It is not the properties of the model, but the properties of acl.